# onDraw() isn't triggered after calling requestLayout()

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I've made a demo following [this article](https://www.codeday.top/2016/11/22/4099.html) but it seems incorrect. The ImageView named `id_meinv` work normally.

However, there are several things happen to the ImageView named `id_qiqiu`.

First, when I click on that ImageView, it triggers requestLayout() that I understand will call `onMeasure()`, on `onSizeChanged()` then `onDraw()` but somehow just `onMeasure()` is called. Why this happen?

Second, `onDraw()` is called only I scroll. (Of course, it still occurs error cause mRoundRect isn't instantiated in `onSizeChanged()`). I also do not understand why.

Comment: just call `invalidate()` method after `requestLayout()` to draw next frame.

Comment: @AnasAltair: Thank you but this is not what i want to ask

Comment: `requestLayout()` doesn't call `onDraw()` method, look at [TextView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#3199) it calls `invalidate()` with `requestLayout()`.

Comment: @AnasAltair `requestLayout()` invokes `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` while `invalidate()` invokes `onDraw()`. Why `onDraw()` is the last to be called although I call `invalidate()` before `requestLayout()`?